# How do I view certificate Safari is using when it reports "not secure"

Tags: apache, ssl, safari

I have a website with a certificate that is auto renewed via Let's Encrpyt and has been working for years. I never had any problems but I just noticed Safari is reporting it as "not secure." But it's fine on Chrome and the timestamp of the cert on the server is Feb 12. I'd like to the view the certificate Safari is using to figure out what's going on but I see no way to view it. I'm running apache. Any ideas?